# Subscript out of Range Printing Cells

Tags: vba, excel

My problem is the part where the cells start to add up on the line below

`currentsheet.Cells(b, a) = currentsheet.Cells(b, a) + Workbooks(d).Sheets(c).Cells(b, a)`.

It throws me

> Subscript out of range

My code is supposed to be taking numbers from multiple charts from three different workbooks and putting it into one main worksheet in another workbook, while adding all the numbers from each chart. All the worksheets are similarly named and formatted.

```
Sub bringbookstogether()

Dim currentsheet As Worksheet
Set currentsheet = Application.ActiveSheet

'assigns the number to start with
Dim a, b, c, d As Integer

a = 4
b = 6
c = 3
d = 1

Dim wsheet As Worksheet
Set wsheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(c)

Dim wbook As Workbook

'assigns workbook numbers
If (d = 1) Then
    Set wbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mminchuk\Documents\Updated MaintPrep Sheets\MaintPrep Sheet 1st.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksAlways)
    Else
    If (d = 2) Then
        Set wbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mminchuk\Documents\Updated MaintPrep Sheets\MaintPrep Sheet 2nd.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksAlways)
        Else
        If (d = 3) Then
            Set wbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mminchuk\Documents\Updated MaintPrep Sheets\MaintPrep Sheet 3rd.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksAlways)
        End If
    End If
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'End if it's done with all the workbooks

Do Until (d = 4)

'Looks for the sheet that has the same name
If (wsheet.Name = currentsheet.Name) Then


    currentsheet.Cells(b, a) = currentsheet.Cells(b, a) + Workbooks(d).Sheets(c).Cells(b, a)
    a = a + 1
    b = b + 1

    If a = 51 Then

        If b = 99 Then

        End If
    End If
End If


d = d + 1
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set wsheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(c)` you want `wsheet` to be always the third sheet of activeworkbook? it does not work like that. You need to set it each time that workbook changes. Your code is an absolute mess. You don't need an if statement and a loop to do this. Think about your approach.

Comment: It'll definitely need some help, but that's where we come in.  B & A are getting incremented on each pass.  I'm betting it quickly goes outside the range that's there.  You can loop over the cells and workbooks, as they're typed as collections.  `for loops` may make it easier to read.

Comment: @Jimmy Smith In a previous question I asked people about a crash that was happening and they told me it was because I had too much loops

Comment: @Masoud for wsheet I have couple of other sheets that start before it, so I  am avoiding them, but I did realize that i forgot to have continue. Also, how does it look at the next worksheet, workbook, cell without an if statement and loop?

Comment: Why abcd variables? Those could be named more appropriately.

Comment: How many workbooks do you have open?  You obviously have the workbook containing the macro open, and your code opens another one ("MaintPrep Sheet 1st.xlsm") but, unless you have others open at the start of your code, `Workbooks(3)` will give an error because you only have two workbooks open.